How to build a dynamic nested category structure in MongoDB
I have a category collection that each of category have name, parentId, level and slug fields. They have basically a structure like that:
{
  _id: "...",
  name: "...,
  parentId: "...",
  level: "...",
  slug: "..."
}

I want to create a tree structure like this with mongodb aggregations:
[
  {
    _id: "...",
    name: "Parent 1",
    parentId: null,
    level: 1,
    slug: "...",
    children: [
      {
        _id: "...",
        name: "Child 1",
        parentId: "...",
        level: 2,
        slug: "...",
        children: [
          {
            _id: "...",
            name: "Sub child 1",
            parentId: "...",
            level: 3,
            slug: "...",
            children: [
              {
                _id: "...",
                name: "...",
                parentId: "...",
                level: 4,
                slug: "...",
                children: ["..."],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        _id: "...",
        name: "Child 2",
        parentId: "...",
        level: 2,
        slug: "...",
        children: [
          ... same as child 1
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: "...",
    name: "Parent 2",
    parentId: null,
    level: 1,
    slug: "...",
    children: [
      ... same as parent 1
    ],
  },
]

Are there any way to achieve this? I saw $graphlookup but I couldn't figure out how to create a tree structure with aggregation.

What specifically could you not figure out? The first example in the docs is a good place to start. Provide example documents , show your aggregation query. Also, generating the result as a nested documents within nested documents is not easily usable. You're better off get the document and using the item order/index in the array of document hierarchy.

As @aneroid has already pointed out, recursive structure with dynamic level of nesting is considered an antipattern in MongoDB and you should avoid it. Nevertheless, you can use the above link to build it if you insists.

@ray Thank you. My question is no different from you mentioned. That aggregation solved my issue. I searched before but I couldn't find that question you mentioned.

@aneroid Do you mean I get my all categories and use JS to create the nested structure?

@MesutÇiftçi Glad that it helps. Feel free to close the question as a duplicate so this post can serve as a signpost to lead future readers to the solution.

@MesutÇiftçi Get the categories as a list/array of related documents and use the depthField to determine how nested it's supposed to be. That's easier to lookup and use, even in JS. But if you definitely want it nested, see the example Mongo Playground in the duplicate-question's answer.
